# Naming a tar file with date

Tags: linux, shell, date, tar

I want to name a tar file with the date, but what i try isn't working, see the code below for better explanation, and what a i have to do?

```
date=$( date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S )
tar -czf ${imageName-$date}.tar.gz ${imageBasename} 2>>$ERRORLOG
```

The image name is a variable that stores a name of an image, like: `win-ser-rdp`

I had tried too:

```
tar -czf ${imageName}:${date}.tar.gz ${imageBasename} 2>>$ERRORLOG
```

Didn't work out too :(

Thanks to all the help :D

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Did you get an error message? If so, show it to us.

Comment: no one error messages appear, the terminal just stops on the process of that line. The script stop, and i have to press Ctrl+C.

Comment: if tar encounters a targetfile of form `foo:bar` it will assume that it is a *remote* file `bar` on host `foo`. i'm not sure whether you *can* create a file with a colon in it's name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your filenames and variables are incorrect:

```
${imageName-$date}
```

Should be

```
${imageName}${date}
```

and

```
${imageName}:${date}.tar.gz
```

is going to be interpreted as an NFS location because of the `:` in the name, e.g. `server:filename`. Replace the `:` with a `-` or other non-special character.

Comment: when i try `${imageName}:${date}.tar.gz` the script returns a error:

tar(child): Cannot connect to vm-win-rdp: resolve failed
tar: Child returned status 128
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: And when i try: `${imageName}${date}` it shows the same error message but the first line instead of the "Cannot connect to vm-win-rdp: resolve failed", it shows: "Cannot connect to vm-win-rdp2013-10-16_12: resolve failed"

Comment: "resolve failed"? sounds like an incorrect hostname or dns failure. Stuff an `echo` in front of the tar command, e.g. `echo tar ....` so you can see EXACTLY what your script is generating.

Comment: lol, I'm not even using internet for this script...Ok I'll try that.

Comment: It generates the same thing, the error output is redirect to the errorLog that i've created `2>>$ERRORLOG`

Comment: @RafaelNunes whenever you have a colon (`:`) in your script, then you *are* using "the internet for this script", simply because this is the way to tell `tar` that you want to access a remote ressource. since  `${date}` contains colons as well, this is where you get the troubles...

Comment: thanks, my date is defined as: `date=$( date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S )`, so i realize that is the problem! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is the `:` in the file name, which is treated specially by GNU tar.

On my own system, where I have a directory named `foo`, I get this:

```
$ tar zcf foo:42.tar.gz foo
tar (child): Cannot connect to foo: resolve failed
tar: Child returned status 128
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
$
```

There doesn't seem to be any way to escape the `:` character -- but you can inhibit the special interpretation with the `--force-local` option (thanks to Daniel Serodio for pointing this out).

Colon characters in file names, though they're legal, are typically a bad idea anyway. For example, you probably wouldn't be able to access the file via `scp`.

Here's the relevant section from the [GNU tar manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/file.html) (`info tar` and go to section 6.1):

> To specify an archive file on a device attached to a remote machine,
>   use the following:
>
> `--file=hostname:/dev/file-name`
>
> tar will set up the remote connection, if possible, and prompt you for
>   a username and password. If you use `--file=@hostname:/dev/file-name`,
>   tar will attempt to set up the remote connection using your username
>   as the username on the remote machine.

When I make file names that include a timestamp, I usually use `YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS`

```
$(date +%F-%H%M%S)
```

or you can use `YYYY-MM-DD_HH_MM_SS` if you prefer

```
$(date +%F-%H_%M_%S)
```

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation about it! I got the solution!

Comment: From the GNU tar manual: _You can If you need to use a file whose name includes a colon, then the remote tape drive behavior can be inhibited by using the ‘--force-local’ option._

Answer (score 1):

try avoiding all colons in the tarfilename, as this will make `tar` attempt to output to a *remote* file:

```
 date=$( date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S )
 tar -czf ${imageName}-${date}.tar.gz ${imageBasename} 2>>${ERRORLOG}
```